# superset slice query error

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle, apache-superset

When press the Query button on the slice page of superset,
The following error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/superset/viz.py", line 251, in get_payload
    data = self.get_data(df)
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/superset/viz.py", line 1106, in get_data
    row = df.groupby(self.groupby).sum()[self.metrics[0]].copy()
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4416, in groupby
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1699, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 392, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "/home/sf400002285/superset_env/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2690, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'SCODE'
```

SQL query is follows.

```
SELECT "SCODE",
       "sum__COUNT"
FROM
  (SELECT "SCODE" AS "SCODE",
          sum(COUNT) AS "sum__COUNT"
   FROM
     (SELECT CASE 性別コード
                 WHEN 5 THEN 
                 WHEN 6 THEN '男性既婚'
                 WHEN 7 THEN '女性独身'
                 WHEN 8 THEN '女性既婚'
                 else 'その他'
             END as scode ,
             COUNT(*) count
      FROM 顧客特定
      GROUP BY 性別コード) expr_qry
   GROUP BY "SCODE"
   ORDER BY sum(COUNT) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 50000
```

version
superset = 0.19.1
cx_Oracle = 5.3

Please tell me how to solve it

Comment: I have no idea what superset is but based on your SQL syntax it looks like you're creating an unnamed column containing the string "SCODE". You need to remove quotes in your Select statement.

Comment: not sure that japanese name for tables is supported. Old versions of superset use pytthon 2, therefore, it requires ascii encoding. And jap is utf-8